# don't understand why the following VBA snippet is throwing error 52

Tags: excel, vba

The following snippet is throwing Error 52 - Bad file name or number and I don't know why:

```
Private Sub InitializeLogFile()
  Dim fileNumber As Integer

  filename = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
  LOG_FULL_FILENAME = "D:\data\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\My Documents\" + filename + "_" + Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hh:mm:ss") + ".log"

  MsgBox LOG_FULL_FILENAME

  fileNumber = FreeFile

  MsgBox fileNumber

  Open LOG_FULL_FILENAME For Append As #fileNumber

  Print #fileNumber, Date & " - " & ThisWorkbook.Name & " opened. "
  Print #fileNumber,

  Close #fileNumber
End Sub
```

Could someone please point out my error?

Comment: which line is throwing the error? and what is `FreeFile`?

Comment: Isn't `FreeFile` used to get the next free file number? The error is on `Open LOG_FULL_FILENAME For Append As #fileNumber`

Comment: @Scott: Why are you asking the OP what FreeFile is? Have a look at the documentation, he's looking for help not further confusion. I won't downrate but the comment wasn't too helpful.

Comment: I'd try changing the plus signs to ampersands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the error is in this line:

```
LOG_FULL_FILENAME = "D:\data\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\My Documents\" + filename + "_" + Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hh:mm:ss") + ".log"
```

specificly, from `Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hh:mm:ss")`

you can't have a `:` in a file name

Filenames cannot contain `\/:*?"<>|`

try: `Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")`

Comment: Ya I found that out not long after.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `Option Explicit` and initialise all variables.

Secondly, if the workbookname is eg. "Book1", then `(InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)` results in -1. And calling `Left(..., -1)` produces your runtime error.

Use the debugger and you'll see.

Comment: By the way, I supposed that your file with that particular name already exists. If not you might want to consider creating it, something along the line of: `Open strPathAndFile For Output Access Write Lock Write As #iFileNumber`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my Workbook name isn't as you say (-1), I just checked.

Comment: Then does the file that you try to open exist? When stepping through with the debugger, which line does the code stop and what value have the local variables? Supply some more information, please. Let's start with the values of `ThisWorkbook.Name`, `filename` and `LOG_FULL_FILENAME`

Comment: This issue would only be valid for newly created workbooks or workbooks that had had their extensions removed. While it's a valid potential issue in the code and should probably be corrected, but it holds no bearing for the error being asked about.

Comment: Well, Olle, why don't you +1 the answer then? ;-) That's how SO works.